# Flutter : How to update db which is fetched from rest api and save it to db.The data needs to be updated when pull to refresh

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I need data to be updated when pulled to refresh. I am fetching data from json url and saving the data to the db and displaying it in listview builder, but the data is static whenever the json api is updating the data is not being updated,So please help me doing so. I have used the example from [here](https://camposha.info/flutter-sqflite-insertselectshow/). Below is my code

articles.dart

```
class Articleslist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Articleslist({this.title}) : super();
  final String title;
  _OurArticleslistPageState createState() => new _OurArticleslistPageState();
}

class _OurArticleslistPageState extends State<Articleslist> {
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
  new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  List<ArticleslistData> articleslist = [];
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appIdForAndroid);
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appIdForIOS);
    }
    _getOurArticleslist(0);
    dbHelper.countItems().then((val) {
      if (val == 0) {
        _getOurArticleslist(0);
      } else {
        dbHelper.readdb().then((list) {
          print("The Last nid and Pageno is : ");
          print(list[list.length - 1]['nid']);
          print(list[list.length - 1]['pageno']);
          pageno = list[list.length - 1]['pageno'] + 1;
          _getOurArticleslist1(pageno);
        });
      }
    });

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        dbHelper.readdb().then((list) {
          pageno = list[list.length - 1]['pageno'] + 1;
          _getOurArticleslist1(pageno);
        });
        // if we scroll up to bottom of the page
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
//    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _getOurArticleslist1(int pageno) async {
    if (this.mounted) {
      var data = await http.get('$BaseUrl/rest/articles?page=$pageno');
      if (data.contentLength == 5) {
        print('ಲೋಡ್ ಮಾಡಲು ಇನ್ನಷ್ಟು ಲೇಖನಗಳು ಇಲ್ಲ');
      } else {
        if (context != null) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
            content: new Text("ಲೋಡ್ ಮಾಡಲಾಗುತ್ತಿದೆ. ದಯವಿಟ್ಟು ನಿರೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ..."),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1600),
          ));
        }
      }

      if (data.statusCode == 200) {
        if (this.mounted) {
          setState(() {
            var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));
            for (var e in jsonData) {
              if (e['field_image'] == '[]') {
                e['field_image'] = 'No img';
              }
              ArticleslistData article = ArticleslistData(
                  e['title'],
                  e['nid'],
                  e['field_image'],
                  e['created'],
                  e['uid'],
                  e['totalcount'],
                  pageno);
              articleslist.add(article);
              dbHelper.saveArticle(article);
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load data ');
      }
      if (this.mounted) {
        return articleslist;
      }
    }
    return null();
  }

  _getOurArticleslist(int pageno) async {
    if (this.mounted) {
      var data = await http.get('$BaseUrl/rest/articles?page=$pageno');
      if (data.contentLength == 5) {
        print('ಲೋಡ್ ಮಾಡಲು ಇನ್ನಷ್ಟು ಲೇಖನಗಳು ಇಲ್ಲ');
      } else {
        if (context != null) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
            content: new Text("ಲೋಡ್ ಮಾಡಲಾಗುತ್ತಿದೆ. ದಯವಿಟ್ಟು ನಿರೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ..."),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1600),
          ));
        }
      }

      if (data.statusCode == 200) {
        var listfromdb;
        if (this.mounted) {
          setState(() {
            var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));
            dbHelper.readdb().then((list) {
              listfromdb = list;
              print('Listfromdb count is');
              print(listfromdb.length);
              if (listfromdb.length == 0) {
                print('\n\nInside listfromdb.length == 0\n\n');
                for (var e in jsonData) {
                  if (e['field_image'].toString() == '[]') {
                    e['field_image'] = 'No img';
                  }
                  ArticleslistData article = ArticleslistData(
                      e['title'],
                      e['nid'],
                      e['field_image'],
                      e['created'],
                      e['uid'],
                      e['totalcount'],
//                      e['body'],
                      pageno);
                  articleslist.add(article);
                  dbHelper.saveArticle(article);
                }
              }
              if (pageno == 0) {
                print('Inside pageno == 0\n\n');
                for (var e = 0; e < jsonData.length; e++) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < listfromdb.length; i++) {
                    print(jsonData[e]['nid'] + ',' + listfromdb[i]['nid']);
                    if (jsonData[e]['nid'] == listfromdb[i]['nid']) {
                      break;
                    } else {
                      if (jsonData[e]['field_image'].toString() == '[]') {
                        jsonData[e]['field_image'] = 'No img';
                      }
                      ArticleslistData article = ArticleslistData(
                          jsonData[e]['title'],
                          jsonData[e]['nid'],
                          jsonData[e]['field_image'],
                          jsonData[e]['created'],
                          jsonData[e]['uid'],
                          jsonData[e]['totalcount'],
                          listfromdb[listfromdb.length - 1]['pageno']);
                      print(article);
                      articleslist.add(article);
                      dbHelper.saveArticle(article);
                      e++;
                    }
                  }
                  break;
                }
              } else if (listfromdb.length != 0) {
                print(' Inside listfromdb.length != 0\n\n');
                for (var e in jsonData) {
                  if (e['field_image'].toString() == '[]') {
                    e['field_image'] = 'No img';
                  }
                  print(e['nid']);
                  ArticleslistData article = ArticleslistData(
                      e['title'],
                      e['nid'],
                      e['field_image'],
                      e['created'],
                      e['uid'],
                      e['totalcount'],
                      pageno);
                  articleslist.add(article);
                  dbHelper.saveArticle(article);
                }
              }
            });
          });
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load data ');
      }
      if (this.mounted) {
        return articleslist;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<List<ArticleslistData>> fetchEmployeesFromDatabase() async {
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    var dbHelper = DBHelper();
    Future<List<ArticleslistData>> articles = dbHelper.getArticles();
    return articles;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: new FutureBuilder<List<ArticleslistData>>(
            future: fetchEmployeesFromDatabase(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print('Snapshot has data');
                if (snapshot.data == []) {
                  return new Text(
                      'Poor Connection, Please wait or Try refreshing the content');
                } else {
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
                    onRefresh: fetchEmployeesFromDatabase,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var imgUrl = snapshot.data[index].img.toString();
                        imgUrl = imgUrl.replaceAll("\"", "");
                        imgUrl = BaseUrl + imgUrl.toString();
                        print('\n Image Url: $imgUrl \n');
                        var title = snapshot.data[index].title;
                        title = title.replaceAll("&quot;", '"');
                        title = title.replaceAll("&#039;", "'");
                        var views = snapshot.data[index].totalcount;

                        return Container(
                          child: SizedBox.fromSize(
//                            child: GestureDetector(
                            child: new Card(
                              elevation: 2.0,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print('Tapped : ${snapshot.data[index].nid}');
                                      print(index);
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => DetailPage(
                                                snapshot.data[index].title,
                                                snapshot.data[index].img,
                                                snapshot.data[index].nid,
                                                snapshot.data[index].uid,
                                              )));
                                    },
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 25.0),
                                      leading: Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          border: new Border(
                                              right: new BorderSide(
                                                  width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey)),
                                        ),
                                        child: imgUrl == 'No img'
                                            ? new Image.asset(
                                          'images/placeholder.png',
                                          height: 100,
                                          width: 100,
                                        )
                                            : FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                          placeholder: 'images/placeholder.png',
                                          image: imgUrl,
                                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      title: Text(
                                        title,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                      ),
                                      subtitle: Text(
                                        'ಲೇಖಕರು : ' + snapshot.data[index].uid,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Divider(height: .0),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          new Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye,size: 14.0),
                                          Center(
                                            child: views == null
                                                ? new Text('')
                                                : new Text('   ${snapshot.data[index].totalcount}  ಓದು'),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 40,
                                        child: FlatButton(
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: <Widget>[
//                                              Padding(
//                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
//                                                child:
//                                              ),
                                                Image.asset('images/share-icons.png',scale: 5.0),
                                                new Text('  ಹಂಚಿಕೊಳ್ಳಿ')
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            onPressed: (){
                                              var nid = articleslist[index].nid;
                                              var url = '$BaseUrl/node/' + nid;
                                              Share.share(url);
                                            }),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return new Text(
                  "${snapshot.error}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black),
                );
              }
              return new Container(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ArticleslistData {
  final String title;
  final String nid;
  final String img;
  final String created;
  final String uid;
  final String totalcount;
  int pageno;

  ArticleslistData(this.title, this.nid, this.img, this.created, this.uid,
      this.totalcount, this.pageno);
}
```

dbhelper.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:models/Article/articleslist.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "test.db");
    // await deleteDatabase(path);
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }

  killDb() async{
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "test.db");
    await deleteDatabase(path);
    //initDb();
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    // When creating the db, create the table
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE Employee(title TEXT, nid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, img TEXT,created TEXT, uid TEXT, totalcount TEXT, pageno INTEGER )");
    print("Created tables");
  }

  readdb() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Employee');
    //  return dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
    //   return await txn.rawDelete('SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE lastname = ?', ['48670']);
    // });
  }

  cleardb() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      return await txn.rawDelete('DELETE FROM Employee WHERE firstname = ?', ['test']);
    });
  }
  countItems() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    var count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee'));
    return count;
  }

  void saveArticle(ArticleslistData article) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      return await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO Employee(title, nid, img, created, uid, totalcount, pageno ) VALUES(' +
              '\'' +
              article.title +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              article.nid +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              article.img +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              article.created +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              article.uid +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              article.totalcount +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              article.pageno.toString() +
              '\'' +
              ')');
    });
  }

  Future<List<ArticleslistData>> getArticles() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY nid DESC;');
    List<ArticleslistData> articles = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      articles.add(new ArticleslistData(list[i]["title"], list[i]["nid"], list[i]["img"], list[i]["created"], list[i]['uid'],list[i]['totalcount'], list[i]['pageno']));
    }
    return articles;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have everything right but you need to setState() to tell flutter to rebuild the UI.

If you're not using a state management solution just do this.

Convert to stateless widget then.

```
onRefresh: () {
SetState() {
fetchEmployeesFromDatabase();
}
}
```

Comment: I have checked with updating already existing app with new build but on refresh it only gets the same data and not updating the new articles to table.